# How to make HTTP server with port not 80 available for network?

Tags: python, sockets, port

I currently have the problem that I have a server script running on one computer as `localhost:12123`. I can connect to it using the same computer but using another computer in the same network does not connect to it (says it does not exist). Firewall is disabled.

Does it have to do with permissions?

The socket is created by a python file using `BaseHTTPServer`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It probably has to do with binding to localhost, instead to the actual LAN interface (e.g. 192.168.1.x) or all interfaces (sometimes referred as 0.0.0.0).

This code would start an instance that binds to all interfaces (not only localhost)

```
def run(server_class=BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer,
        handler_class=BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    server_address = ('0.0.0.0', 12123)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

`server_adress` has to be `(0.0.0.0, 12123)` see: **0.0.0.0**

Answer (score 1):

Bind to 0.0.0.0 or the outside IP address instead, obviously.